# Mysql issue with dns resolution. Spring boot - Connect to mysql db using a read-only user

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, dns, spring-data-jpa

I have a read-only user, when I try start my spring boot application I get a exception (using password yes).

User privileges:

```
mysql> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myuser@%                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mydb'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxx' |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mydb`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Class DatabaseConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "mydbEntityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"co.com.xxx.persistence.telemercadeo"}
)
public class DatabaseConfig {

    /**
     * Logger to register events.
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfig.class);

    /**
     * Returns a data source for database connection (source).
     *
     * @return {@link DataSource}. Database connection representation.
     */
    @Bean(name = "mydbDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mydb.jdbc")
    public DataSource sourceDataSource() {
        LOGGER.info("Loading data source for source");        
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mydbEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("mydbDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("co.com.xxx.model.telemercadeo")
                .persistenceUnit("mydb")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mydbTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("mydbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

My application.properties:

```
mydb.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.200.5:3306/mydb
mydb.jdbc.username=myuser
mydb.jdbc.password=mypass
mydb.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

When I start the app I get the next trace:

```
2017-03-09 08:34:34.635 [main] INFO  c.c.n.c.e.c.DatabaseConfig - Loading data source for source
2017-03-09 08:34:34.678 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'mydb
2017-03-09 08:34:34.678 [main] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: mydb
    ...]
2017-03-09 08:34:34.740 [main] ERROR o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'SUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.COM' (using password: YES)
2017-03-09 10:02:26.926 [main] WARN  o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'myuser'@'SUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.COM' (using password: YES)
```

My suspicions:

- Can not connect to a db with a read-only user.
- Access denied for user 'myuser'@'**SUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.COM**'. Why appears the domain?

With a user with all the privileges there is no problem. But I need connect with a read-only user.

Mysql version: **5.1**

**EDIT**

After restart mysql server with parameter --skip-name-resolve true (as @wangyuntao suggested), the exception change to:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'192.168.200.1' (using password: YES)
```

If db's ip is 192.168.200.5, why exception is Access denied for user 'myuser'@'**192.168.200.1**' (using password: YES)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly grant access from localhost

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mydb'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxx' 
GRANT SELECT ON `mydb`.* TO 'my_user'@'localhost'
```

Comment: I connet to remote IP.

Comment: Ah okay, `192.168.***` looks like a local address @victorpacheco3107

Comment: Ok, I'll test and tell you.

Comment: I granted: GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'SUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.COM' . I can connet by command line, but I get the same exception: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'SUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.COM' (using password: YES)  @baao

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure, but if you like, you can try **skip-name-resolve** option.

As the document says:

[server-system-variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html)

> This variable is set from the value of the --skip-name-resolve option. If it is OFF, mysqld resolves host names when checking client connections. If it is ON, mysqld uses only IP numbers; in this case, all Host column values in the grant tables must be IP addresses or localhost. See Section 9.12.5.2, “DNS Lookup Optimization and the Host Cache”.

[host-cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html)

> To disable DNS host name lookups, start the server with the --skip-name-resolve option. In this case, the server uses only IP addresses and not host names to match connecting hosts to rows in the MySQL grant tables. Only accounts specified in those tables using IP addresses can be used. (Be sure that an account exists that specifies an IP address or you may not be able to connect.)

---

**EDIT**

According to MySQL document, here is my test and it works for me.

1. CREATE USER 'jeffrey' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
2. GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO 'jeffrey';

Then you can connect to your db from other machines, e.g.

```
mysql -ujeffrey -pmypass -hYOUR_DB_IP
```

Comment: I have done these things. But now the excepption change: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'192.168.200.1' (using password: YES) Please check the server.log for more details. When db's ip is 192.168.200.5

Comment: 192.168.200.1 should be the IP of your application's machine?

Comment: Are you sure the user and password you are using to connect to db is correct?

Comment: Please refer to the document of [GRANT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) for more details.

Comment: the IP 192.168.200.1 is not application's machine. I'm sure that password is correct, I can connect using command line, but when I try to connect  using Mysql Workbench this show same message.

Comment: When I connect using command line and run the command show grants this show GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mydb'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxx' GRANT SELECT ON `mydb`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'